# Set Entry widget values dynamically in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a window to browse a folder containing necessary files. I am using *tkFileDialog* for the same. I want to set the value of Entry widget equal to this selected folder. Initially when no folder is selected it will be null. As soon as I select the folder, the path of the selected folder should appear in the Entry widget. The user should be able to modify.Below mentioned is the code for the same.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

class Checkit:
    root = Tk()
    #default string to be displayed in the entry of path        
    path_to_file = StringVar(root, value="abc")

    def __init__(self):     
    self.inputDetail()

    def inputDetail(self):              
        #copy the root window
        master = self.root

        #create frame for details in the root window
        details_frame = Frame(master)
        details_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #Create the Labels
        papercode_label = Label(details_frame, text="Paper code:")
        subject_label = Label(details_frame, text="Subject:")
        chapter_label = Label(details_frame, text="Chapter:")
        batch_label = Label(details_frame, text="Batch:")
        ansFolder_label = Label(details_frame, text="Folder containing answer-keys:")

        #create entry for the labels
        papercode_entry = Entry(details_frame)
        subject_entry = Entry(details_frame)
        chapter_entry = Entry(details_frame)
        batch_entry = Entry(details_frame)
        ansFolder_entry = Entry(details_frame)

        #create button to add path
        path = Button(details_frame, text="Browse", command= lambda: self.addpath(details_frame))

        #button to enter the next window
        next = Button(details_frame, text="Next", command= lambda: self.checkOmr(details_frame, master))

        #Use grid layout to place labels and entry
        papercode_label.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        papercode_entry.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

        subject_label.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        subject_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

        chapter_label.grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        chapter_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)

        batch_label.grid(row=6, sticky=W)
        batch_entry.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)

        ansFolder_label.grid(row=8, sticky=W)
        path.grid(row=9, sticky=W, columnspan=2)
        next.grid(row=10, sticky=E, columnspan=2)

        master.mainloop()

    def checkOmr(self, old_frame, master):
        #destoy the  old frame
        old_frame.destroy()

        #create frame for details in the root window
        inputPath_frame = Frame(master)
        inputPath_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #create label to input folder containing 
        omrFolder_label = Label(inputPath_frame, text="Folder containing OMR sheet to be checked:")     

        #create button to add path
        path = Button(inputPath_frame, text="Browse", command= lambda: self.addpath(inputPath_frame))

        selected_path = Entry(inputPath_frame, textvariable=self.path_to_file)

        #place the label and button on the grid     
        omrFolder_label.grid(row=0, sticky=W)       
        path.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        selected_path.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        #master.mainloop()

    def addpath(self, details_frame):
        self.path_to_file = askdirectory(parent=details_frame,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')     

if __name__=='__main__':
    handle = Checkit()
```

Here I am trying to change the modifying the self. path_to_file value on the click of the button. I tried to print the value of self.path_to_file value in *addpath()*. It gives correct result there but the value in the Entry selected_path in *checkOMR()* does not modify.

Can somebody suggest what changes should I make to make that thing possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
self.path_to_file = askdirectory(...)
```

Before this line of code runs, `self.path_to_file` is an instance of a `StringVar`. After this line of code has run, `self.path_to_file` is reset to be just a string.

Assuming you want `self.path_to_file` to remain an instance of `StringVar`, you need to change that line to this:

```
path = askdirectory(...)
self.path_to_file.set(path)
```